# How to navigate between portlets using special portlet for navigation

Tags: java, liferay, portlet

I mean that I have portlet by which I can go to other portlets clicking on the link, like portlet menu. So on the page I will always see two portlets: for navigation and chosen. I realy do not know how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do some research. Look into Portlet Events - part of the JSR 286 spec.

Basically one Portlet will act as a menu portlet. When you select a link in this portlet, you will trigger a portlet event and pass some identifier. The second portlet will be configured to receive the same type of portlet event. You will override the `processEvent()` method of the receiving portlet and then do whatever you need to do.

If you don't understand Portlet Events or portlets, then I suggest you do a search on the internet for JSR 286 and portlet events for your specific server and go through some basic tutorials